# Is there a way to make a QR code that connects to a website, but in order for people to join, they have to pay a fee for a limited time account?

Tags: php, qr-code, progressive-web-apps

First I wanted to clarify that this is neither a recommendation question nor a problem. I am making a PWA and in general I am new to coding/html/php based stuff. So my concern is if there is a way to make this thing work out. I have already managed to make a login system that someone has to create an account in order to login etc etc. I'm currently thinking that since I have already managed that, if there is a way for someone else (other than the customers that already have accounts), to join the app, by scanning a QR Code that when scanned will ask for a small fee payment in order to join the PWA based website, or even download the app.

The only thing I know and have tried is the QR code creation but I don't think that helps in my request.

Expected results: A QR-code that when scanned, asks for a fee payment, either paypal or whatever in order to gain access to the PWA through a limited time  account (say like 3 days).

Is there a way this could be done with php tokens ?

Comment: You need to narrow down/break down your question if you're going to get any useful answers. It sounds like you've already got a website/app with a login system and you know how to make a QR code that points at a url. A good question might be "How can I make accounts time-limited using [login system]?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QR code is just a means of encoding some text so it can be scanned easily.

It has no mechanisms for taking payment or embedding any kind of software.

For that, you'll need to look to traditional approaches such as having the QR code contain a URL pointing to a "Login or buy an account" page.

Comment: I guess a limited time account signup page with a QR code linking to it could be the answer? If so, is it possible to connect the "limited-time account login" with "the normal account login" to the same login system. Because generally there will be "bought accounts" that have access to the PWA indefinitely , but also the "limited-time" ones for a day or two. What I mean is, would both of the signups end up to the same login system or would there have to be a second one?

Comment: Surely it is just a matter of adding an expiry time flag to the account profile?

Comment: Ok then. Going to get started in researching that then. Thank you very much for the insights and have a nice day.

Comment: The other option would be to make accounts free, but have a 'premium' flag with an end time that you need to access any content. Accounts would be free to make, and when users bought time it would set their premium end time to current time + bought time.